# How to do a fetch inside a fetch?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am confused because I have never used a fetch inside a fetch. So basically I have a fetch for all the 'provider' and another one for all the the product of the provider. But I don't know if the where I use is the right one for that kind of situation. So this is what I did so far but the fetch inside a fetch confuse me a lot am I on the right way? Also I have some scalar variable mistake here --

> ' SET @valeurTotal += @stock * @prix'

```sql
DECLARE @stock int, @nom VARCHAR(15), @prix MONEY, @paysD VARCHAR(15), @nomFourni VARCHAR(15);
DECLARE @noFourni VARCHAR(15);
DECLARE @valeurTotal float;

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE valeurStock
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE db_curseur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT nom_fournisseur, nom_pays
        FROM produit
        JOIN fournisseur ON produit.no_fournisseur = fournisseur.no_fournisseur
        JOIN ville ON fournisseur.nom_ville = ville.nom_ville
        WHERE nom_pays = 'Canada'

    DECLARE curseur_produit CURSOR FOR
        SELECT produit.nom_produit, produit.prix_unitaire, produit.unite_en_stock
        FROM produit
        JOIN fournisseur ON produit.no_fournisseur = fournisseur.no_fournisseur
        WHERE fournisseur.no_fournisseur = produit.no_fournisseur

OPEN db_curseur;
FETCH db_curseur INTO @nomFourni, @paysD;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    FETCH curseur_produit INTO @nom, @prix, @stock
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @valeurTotal += @stock * @prix
            FETCH curseur_produit INTO @nom, @prix, @stock
        END

    print 'Le numéro de produit: ' + CAST(@noProduit AS VARCHAR);
    print 'Le nom du fournisseur: ' + @nom;
    print 'Le prix du produit: ' + CAST(@prix AS VARCHAR);
    print 'Le stock: ' + CAST(@stock AS VARCHAR);
    print 'La valeur total: ' + CAST(@valeurTotal AS VARCHAR);
FETCH db_curseur INTO @nomFourni, @paysD;
END
CLOSE curseur_employe
DEALLOCATE curseur_employe
END
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you need to use cursor ?

Comment: How about in very simple terms, edit your existing post, at the TOP, put what you are TRYING to get, and then show any code / samples.  Apply similar in future posts.